# Can JDBC return a domain object as query result

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a table user in a MySQL database, and I created a class `User` for my project. I would like to get the record directly in a `User` object as in Hibernate, without using Hibernate:

```
User u = (User) session.get(User.class, id);
```

I use a JDBC driver.

Is there any way to get a result set as Object like:

```
Statement stmt = db.createStatement();
User u = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user",User.class);
```

I am a lazy programmer, I wouldn't create a list, create a loop to iterate it and set all variables.

I've solved.
@Kayaman I've found ORMlite library.

```
String databaseUrl = "...";
ConnectionSource cs = new JdbcConnectionSource(databaseUrl);
Dao<User,Integer> userDAO = DaoManager.createDao(cs, User.class);

User u = userDAO.queryForId(1);
System.out.println(u.getName());
```

For http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_1.html#Getting-Started

Comment: I don't follow the question.  What result set do you want?

Comment: Yes, for example by using Hibernate that does the mapping for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

What you are asking for is called an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).  JDBC is not an ORM.  Hibernate is an ORM for Java, which uses JDBC to actually connect to and interact with the database server.  EclipseLink is another Java ORM (it is the one included with glassfish).

Comment: @FabrizioFranzè If you don't want to write the resultset mapping yourself, you'll have to use a library.

Comment: Which library I use?